# Firebase Storage not accesing the right url for image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get a Firebase Image into a RecyclerView, and, as my method works only with this type of link:[image]

I was trying to get that link for each image with this code:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Viaje,ListaViajes.MyHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Viaje, MyHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Viaje model) {

            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            StorageReference pathRef = storageReference.child("images").child(model.getUserName()+".jpeg");

            holder.setSitio(model.getSitio().toString());
            holder.setPruebaImagen(pathRef.getDownloadUrl().toString());

            });
        }
```

MyHolder class with my "custom method" (it works well with handed typed urls)

```
public static class MyHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public MyHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
    }
    public void setPruebaImagen(String url)
    {
        ImageView imageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        GlideUtil.loadProfilePhoto(url,imageView );
    }
}
```

The images are located in a folder called images and are named by the user's username, that's why I do the call `model.getUserName()`

[image]

The problem is, no image is actually shown.

The storageReference works fike I think, as it gets the value `gs://benaluma-1522696560348.appspot.com/` , however from then on, I'm lost, maybe it's just a matter of the .child methods syntaxis or the `.getDownloadUrl` method, thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just call toString() on the Task returned by getDownloadURL.  Read the dup issue for details on how it works.

Comment: What is dup issue? Sorry I'm new with Android developing. I can see it's a task, I have to wait for it to complete and then use the result with a string format?

Comment: If you want to use getDownloadURL correctly, follow the instructions in the answer in the other question.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know how to manage the URL then, with my GlideUtil method that receives a string as parameter, what should I put into it, the getResult().toString()?